# How to change the name of an android app which is displayed in the settings menu?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I want to rename my app and I could change
the title / homescreen name via android:label="@string/app_name" in the manifest file.
So far so good.

But: in the Android settings app the old name still appears.
I've tried to change

- the application id in build.gradle
- rootProject.name in settings.gradle
- the package name in the manifest

I've also tried clean project and invalidate caches in Android Studio as well as reinstalling the app.

Where does android derive the name displayed in the settings from?
Do I have to clear some other caches?
Is this a bug in older Android versions?
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried changing the app_name string in res/values/strings.xml?

Comment: Yes, I did that and it changed successfully the homescreen app name and the title, but not the name in the settings :-(

Comment: What do you mean in the settings? In the device's settings? In your own app's setting? If it's in the device, try deleting and installing the app again

Comment: in the android settings app where you can uninstall apps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. A simple reboot of the device did the trick. I do not know why this happens, but it seems that the old name of the application is stored in the device's memory and is not updated when installing an application with a new name.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio on a Windows, macOS or Linux based machine uses the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + R to search your application name in the whole project then replace it with your new app name.

Note:- Uninstall your old app then create a new build